# Issue with logging in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to use looging from a jsp page and I have initialised the loggger as shown.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger( "sample.jsp" );
```

But when I try to log any startements as `logger.log("Sample Output");`, its giving me the following exception.

```
The method log(String, Priority, Object, Throwable) in the type Category is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

Why is this error occurring and how can I solve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call info(), debug(), error(),.. instead of log()

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I am not requesting for clarification or critiquing.

Answer (score 4):

Because there is no such method.

Use more appropriate methods like: `fatal()`, `error()`, `info()`, `debug()` etc.

Check documentation here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html

The error says, method expects these arguments:

```
log(String, Priority, Object, Throwable)
```

But you are passing only `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your JSP

```
<% Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());%>
```